# incorrect checksum in control file error for postgres 9.1.3 data created in osx-Lion and accessed in osx-snow-leopard

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I get the following error when trying to start postgres using the data created in another mac machine.
FATAL:  incorrect checksum in control file

The postgres version is 9.1.3 and the data initialized in snow leopard does not work in Lion and vice-versa. I do not face this issue for postgres v9.0.1. is there any configuration in postgres 9.1.3 which fixes this issue?

Comment: My google session indicated that this is probably a 32/64 bit issue, or a replication thing. What exactly did you do?

Comment: i am not sure how 32 or 64 bit becomes a issue here. There is only one postgres bundle for mac. I have a standalone product which uses postgres. I have my initial data created in a Lion OSX machine, when i try to start postgres with this data in another(snow-leopard) machine it gives the above error.

Comment: Did you migrate the data to 9.1 without dump/restore (see the release notes for 9.1) ? Please tell us what you did.

Comment: The data has been created with v9.1.3 only. It was created on a osx-Lion machine. My software application is packaged with postgres along with this data. In this way initial data goes with application. My assumption is that data created in one mac machine will work in all other mac machines, this is not happening which i could not figure it out.

Comment: @Pavan: your assumption is wrong. The binary files of a PostgreSQL installation can only be moved to a different computer if the operating system (version) is identical and the HW architecture (processor) is identical. Everything else requires a dump and restore (or at least is not supported)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what is surprising is in v9.0.1 this works but when we upgrade to v9.1.3 it fails. In v9.0.1 the data initialized in snow leopard works well in Lion also.

Comment: You can **not** just copy the datafiles from one version to another. You need a dump/restore or use `pg_upgrade` which is clearly documented in the release notes

Comment: sorry if i have not conveyed it clear, let me elaborate the problem in detail. Our application is packaged with initial data along with postgres binaries. The mac binaries previously had postgres v9.0.1 and it works fine in all mac systems(atleast in the machines we have for testing). Recently we updated the application with postgres v9.1.3 and created the data in that version. But this time, the mac binary is working only in the osx version in which it has been created but does not work in other version of osx because the start of postgres fails giving 'incorrect checksum...' exception.

Answer (score 7):

You can't move between systems with different operating systems.  The compiled versions may have different alignment etc.  Do a dump on the old and a restore on the new.

Comment: +1 great answer. You also cannot copy database files between different architectures (32bit vs. 64bit), even if the OS is the same.